# Setting the default virtual host with ISPConfig 3.0.4

Tags: apache, webserver, virtualhost

Im using ISPConfig 3.0.4 With multiple sites running on it already.

I have recently set up multisite wordpress install and want to make this domain (lets say www.domaina.com) to be the default virtual host on the server.  This way when I add a new site (www.domainb.com) it defaults to go there If i do not have a site defination set up in ispconfig set up for domainb.  currently it will go to www.domainc.com as it appears to be set up as the default site.

Does anyone here know how to change it so i can make domaina the default and not domainc where I dont have to make the change everytime i add a new site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have no matching name based vhost, apache will show the first site it finds for the doamin. To have a global default for this case, you can add a default vhost to your httpd.conf before the line:
Include /etc/apache/vhosts/Vhosts_ispconfig.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1>
ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
DocumentRoot /path/to/your/company/website/
</VirtualHost>
```

Dont forget to change the IP, emailaddress and path.

Comment: I was aware of this fix and appreciate you writing it out here for me to use.  What I was really looking for was a way (via setting in ispconfig) to do this automatically this way I did not have to log into the server directly.  I have made this change to the httpd conf file and it is working now.  But is there a way to do it from ISP config?

Answer (score 0):

From ISPConfig, the best way to achieve this is to create a site which will be the first of your websites in an alphabetical order.

For example, `000-default` will work.

Then create a redirection to your main domain (here, `www.domaina.com`).